# Not able to rotate or pan my panorama in three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am not using the default code to do camera rotation in three js which is

```
lat = Math.max( - 85, Math.min( 85, lat ) );
phi = THREE.Math.degToRad( 90 - lat );
theta = THREE.Math.degToRad( lon );
camera.target.x = 100 * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.cos( theta );
camera.target.y = 100 * Math.cos( phi );
camera.target.z = 100 * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.sin( theta );
```

Instead I am doing `lookVector.applyAxisAngle(axis, 0.001);` and so I think I am not able to pan the 360 image with mouse. I have put my code in fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sh60yqfx/32/
Please help.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Made below changes & it seems to be working. Please try locally.

```
function onPointerUp( event ) {
    isUserInteracting = false;
}

 function onPointerMove( event ) {
    if ( isUserInteracting === true ) {
        var clientX = event.clientX || event.touches[ 0 ].clientX;
        var clientY = event.clientY || event.touches[ 0 ].clientY;
        lon = ( onMouseDownMouseX - clientX ) * 0.1 + onMouseDownLon;
        lat = ( clientY - onMouseDownMouseY ) * 0.1 + onMouseDownLat;
    }
}
```

Need to stop interlacing when user stops moving the mouse (or touch ends)

```
function render() {            
        lookVector.set(lon,lat,11);
        lookVector.applyAxisAngle(axis, 0.001);         
        camera.lookAt(lookVector);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);            
}
```

In the `render()` function set the `lookVector` values based on `lon` &`lat` & then make the `camera` to `lookAt` the `lookVector`.

Comment: how do I set lat and lon?

Comment: You are already setting `lat` and `lon` in `function onPointerMove(event)`

Comment: It does work but not exactly how I want.. The problem is i am setting `camera.lookAt` with x,y and z values of my choice(consider hardcoded values and not from default start position) and the camera is rotating and `isUserinterating` is false. On mouse down I'm setting `isUserInteracting` to true and move the mouse. but the camera takes some different position and not last position where it was when isUserInteracting was false. I want the camera to take the same position when I do mouseDown. I am passing the same lookVector from `isUserintearacting` false state still it takes wrong position

Comment: maybe it takes the correct position but on mouseMove lat and lon are not added correctly. I am taking `lat` and `lon` from `pointerMove` function.